# HTML5 Facebook Like Box in Joomla Custom HTML Module

Tags: html, facebook, joomla, facebook-likebox

I'm using the HTML5 code for the Like Box on my website: http://new.woodypointcomms.com.au. For some reason the faces part is displaying some people multiple times. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Comment: Although not touched with facebook api since 5 months but it was a bug in facebook 5 months ago. Reported so many times but they didn't pay attention on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try a [pre-built module version](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/republish/12589) instead of the direct FB widget. Joomla filters HTML content [depending on your settings] which may cause issues. Also try without caching options [Global Configuration] if you've enabled any.